# Get key of a 3 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is dump of how my array looks like. There is inner array called officers and I would want to loop through it and check if there is officer of a specific name and if so I would want to get the index key of the outer array.

```
'edges' => 
    array (size=59)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'source' => int 0
          'target' => int 12
          'officers' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'PARKER, Thomas, Sir' (length=19)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'source' => int 0
          'target' => int 19
          'officers' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'STEVENS, Anne' (length=13)
```

So if I checked for STEVENS, Anne I would want to get key 1.

Here is code I found in a different question it works with 2d arrays but not with 3d array.

```
function array_search_inner ($array, $attr, $val, $strict = FALSE) {
  // Error is input array is not an array
  if (!is_array($array)) return FALSE;
  // Loop the array
  foreach ($array as $key => $inner) {
    // Error if inner item is not an array (you may want to remove this line)
    if (!is_array($inner)) return FALSE;
    // Skip entries where search key is not present
    if (!isset($inner[$attr])) continue;
    if ($strict) {
      // Strict typing
      if ($inner[$attr] === $val) return $key;
    } else {
      // Loose typing
      if ($inner[$attr] == $val) return $key;
    }
  }
  // We didn't find it
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I can suggest quick and short solution, but with strict comparison. And if we talk about strings, I think, the comparison should be strict

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be several index keys that fit the condition, it is reasonable to implement the function as a generator:

```
function getOfficerIndexKey($data, $officerName) {
    foreach ($data['edges'] as $key => $value) {
        in_array($officerName, $value['officers']) && (yield $key);
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate over all found values:

```
foreach (getOfficerIndexKey($data, 'STEVENS, Anne') as $indexKey) {
    // Do something
}
```

As well as just get the first found one:

```
getOfficerIndexKey($data, 'STEVENS, Anne')->current();
```